# Creating a dedicated dock shortcut for my streaming service web page using .desktop files

Tags: firefox, .desktop, shortcuts, ubuntu-dock, url

I'm trying to create a dock shortcut for a streaming service browser application that does not have a native apllication on the ubuntu store. I was able to create the .desktop file and make it work, but whenever I open the application, the page is contained within the firefox icon in the dock and not within it's dedicated icon I created. Moreover whenever I click the shortcut it opens a new page with the same URL (I keep making duplicates instead of restoring the page that was already opened).
Is there a way to make the dock URL shortcut I created function just like a native application, opening the current application whenever I click on it (instead of opening a new window) and be contained within the dock icon I created instead of firefox'?
I noticed the URL changes as I navigate the streaming website, is there a way to solve for this?

My current .desktop file looks like:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Comment=Open crunchyroll web page
Terminal=false
Name=Crunchyroll
Exec=firefox  -new-window https://www.crunchyroll.com/
Type=Application
Icon=/home/username/.local/share/applications/crunchyroll_icon.svg
NoDisplay=false
SingleMainWindow=true
```

P.S.: the last line is apparently not working.